# Why do some github commits don't reflect travis build status?

Tags: github, travis-ci

[image]

I haven't used Travis-CI but I can see that some GitHub commits have a green mark which shows that Travis build has succeeded and some have a red mark which shows that Travis builds failed. But I am wondering why do a few commits don't have any status?

I am looking at the commits of [apache commons-math](https://github.com/apache/commons-math/commits/master).

Comment: Multiple commits were probably pushed at once, with only the most recent triggering a build.

Comment: I see!! So, when a bunch of local commits are pushed to remote, only the most recent commit will trigger the build and hence has a status. Is that right?

Comment: I imagine that's the case. No reason to check a commit if it doesn't matter.

Comment: Makes sense! You can write it as an answer :)

Comment: Found a source for you in the docs, which I just added as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably there were multiple commits locally, which was only pushed after commit `583d9ec`. Given that the status of an old commit is irrelevant, Travis CI ignores those and only builds the most recent ([source](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Skipping-a-build)). If any issues did arise, a build could have still been manually triggered, revealing which commit broke something.